# Is it correct to bring back the Airport Express ticket in the end of trip in Hong Kong?

Tags: trains, hong-kong

I just finished my first travel to Hong Kong, where I used Airport Express to move to Hong Kong station and back to the Airport. However, on the return train, I didn't find the gate to insert my card into. And thus I brought back the ticket to my country.

However, now I'm uneasy about it; it might be that I made a mistake (possibly even crime). I just followed other passengers and no one seemed to insert the card.

But is it correct to bring back the card now? For your information my ticket is one-trip, two-way one which I purchased $180 using my credit card.

Comment: You used the ticket to board the train at Hong Kong station. That turnstile marks the ticket as used. There is no turnstile at the airport since everyone on the train used their ticket when they boarded. You can toss the ticket out, no one wants it back

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is how it is supposed work: in the station (Hong Kong or Kowloon) you go through a turnstile. The turnstile has an RF card reader which can read (and invalidate) the ticket. Typically you need to swipe the ticket over the reading area next to the turnstile but if you are lucky the reader may still see it if it's just in your hand.

After it's read, the turnstile will unlock and you can go through. At this point the ticket is invalidated (or one trip subtracted). You are supposed to keep the ticket since it's also your receipt.

So if you went through a turnstile, your ticket got read and invalidated. If not, you got lucky and have a spare ticket. Same story as if the conductor on the train forgot to punch your ticket. It's not your fault.

Answer (score 3):

There is no crime in taking the ticket. A ticket can often be useful as a receipt for business expenses purposes, especially if you didn't get a receipt when you bought it. I'm not sure how you managed to get to the train without going through a ticket barrier in Hong Kong though. In any case you paid for the journey and have a ticket to prove it.